# Removing an Observer After an Observed Event

Tags: iphone, observer-pattern

I have an object observer that I only need to detect one thing. Once I'm done with it, I'd like to remove it to eliminate overhead.

So it would look something like this:

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*) change context:(void*)context{
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"doingSomething"]){
        if ([object isDoingSomething] == NO) {
                    [my_object setDoingSomething: DO_NOTHING_FOREVER];
                    [my_object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"doingSomething"] // <= ERROR eventually
                }
        }
}
```

This does not work though and throws an error like:

`NSKVOPendingNotificationRelease  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be calling remove observer on the `object`?

```
[object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"doingSomething"];
```

[`removeObserver:forKeyPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/removeObserver%3aforKeyPath%3a) method should be called on the receiver.